# Changing display value with CSS '+' operator

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu using CSS, it's centered around using the following:

```
#submenu_div {
  display: none;
}

#li_id:hover + #submenu_div {
  display: block;
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the fixed HTML for the entire thing.

```
<ul id="main_nav">
  <a href=""><li id="li_id">Home</li></a>
  <ul id="sub_who">                                                                                                                                     
    <li>Foo</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

The #submenu_div is outside the parent div for the ul in which the li the previous code refers to resides. As far as I know, this should work. But I'm obviously doing something wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Then the `div` is a sibling of the `ul` not the `li`, and can't be targeted from the `li `, or its `:hover` event. Incidentally a `div` is not a valid child of a `ul`, so this selector should never match an element.

Comment: I've removed the div, so now I have an li that's supposed to change the display value on hover, followed by the ul whos display value I want to change. Still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The #submenu_div is outside the parent div for the ul in which the li the previous code refers to resides.

The `+` combinator looks *only* for a true sibling element, i.e. an element with the *same parent* as whatever matched the left-hand side of the `+`.  You cannot make it match anything else.  You will need to change either your HTML (so that `#submenu_div` is a true sibling of `#li_id`) or your CSS (so the thing on the LHS of the `+` is a true sibling of `#submenu_div`) or both.

Without seeing the structure of your HTML I cannot give more precise advice.

Comment: I've fixed the HMTL and removed the div since David Thomas said that a div isn't a valid child for a ul, so I'm guessing that stands for an li. Is this what you meant?